# change the style of only first element in an array of class elements using javascript

Tags: javascript

i have this html code that has a list. in my css listName is set to display='none'

when the dom page opens up i need the FIRST element of the class="listName" to show.. obviously this class in js is an array.. can you please show me

i need to make the page more user friendly.  i need one li showing and if the user decides to book more shipments he can click on Add more shipments to show another li

the css file has this

```
.listHolder {
    display: none;
}
```

here is the image of what it looks like now

[image]

```
    <div class="container">
        <div class="listHolder" th:each="freight, itemStat : *{freightsDto}">
            <ul class="list">
                <li class="listName">
                    <div class="row mtp">
                        <div class="col-sm-8 w-50 desc">
                            <label class="row">Item description</label>
                            <input id="addInput" class="row form-control" type="text" th:field="*{freightsDto[__${itemStat.index}__].name}" required="required">
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-sm-2">
                            <div class="inblk mlt custom-control custom-radio custom-control-inline mtp" th:each="modelMap : ${T(com.payara.common.AssetCondition).values()}">
                                <input type="radio" th:field="*{freightsDto[__${itemStat.index}__].assetCondition}" class="custom-control-input" th:value="${modelMap}"> <!-- this works fine with modelMap.displayValue -->
                                <label class="custom-control-label" th:for="${#ids.next('freightsDto[__${itemStat.index}__].assetCondition')}"
                               th:text="${modelMap.displayValue}">Asset condition</label>
                        <!-- this works fine with itemStat.count too -->
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row mtp">
                <div class="col-sm-3 pack">
                    <label for="packaging" class="row custom-control-label">Packaging</label>
                    <select name="Packaging" id="packaging" class="row form-select">
                        <option th:each="modelMap : ${T(com.payara.common.PackageType).values()}"
                                th:value="${modelMap}" th:text="${modelMap.displayValue}" size="50">
                        </option>
                    </select>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-3 dim">
                    <label style="margin-left: 2px;" class="row custom-control-label">Dimensions</label>
                    <div class="input-group mb-3">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" th:field="*{freightsDto[__${itemStat.index}__].length}">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" th:field="*{freightsDto[__${itemStat.index}__].width}">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" th:field="*{freightsDto[__${itemStat.index}__].height}">
                        <div class="input-group-prepend">
                            <span class="input-group-text">L x W x H (inch)</span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-3 wght">
                    <label style="margin-left: 2px;" class="row custom-control-label">Weight</label>
                    <div class="input-group mb-3">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" th:field="*{freightsDto[__${itemStat.index}__].weight}">
                        <div class="input-group-prepend">
                            <span class="input-group-text">lbs</span>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-3 plts">
                    <label class="row custom-control-label">How many pallets</label>
                    <div class="row input-group mb-3">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control"
                               th:field="*{freightsDto[__${itemStat.index}__].pallets}">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

             
            <hr>
              </li>
                                <li class="listName">
                    <div class="row mtp">
                        <div class="col-sm-8 w-50 desc">
                            <label class="row">Item description</label>
                            <input id="addInput" class="row form-control" type="text" th:field="*{freightsDto[__${itemStat.index}__].name}" required="required">
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-sm-2">
                            <div class="inblk mlt custom-control custom-radio custom-control-inline mtp" th:each="modelMap : ${T(com.payara.common.AssetCondition).values()}">
                                <input type="radio" th:field="*{freightsDto[__${itemStat.index}__].assetCondition}" class="custom-control-input" th:value="${modelMap}"> <!-- this works fine with modelMap.displayValue -->
                                <label class="custom-control-label" th:for="${#ids.next('freightsDto[__${itemStat.index}__].assetCondition')}"
                               th:text="${modelMap.displayValue}">Asset condition</label>
                        <!-- this works fine with itemStat.count too -->
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row mtp">
                <div class="col-sm-3 pack">
                    <label for="packaging" class="row custom-control-label">Packaging</label>
                    <select name="Packaging" id="packaging" class="row form-select">
                        <option th:each="modelMap : ${T(com.payara.common.PackageType).values()}"
                                th:value="${modelMap}" th:text="${modelMap.displayValue}" size="50">
                        </option>
                    </select>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-3 dim">
                    <label style="margin-left: 2px;" class="row custom-control-label">Dimensions</label>
                    <div class="input-group mb-3">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" th:field="*{freightsDto[__${itemStat.index}__].length}">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" th:field="*{freightsDto[__${itemStat.index}__].width}">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" th:field="*{freightsDto[__${itemStat.index}__].height}">
                        <div class="input-group-prepend">
                            <span class="input-group-text">L x W x H (inch)</span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-3 wght">
                    <label style="margin-left: 2px;" class="row custom-control-label">Weight</label>
                    <div class="input-group mb-3">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" th:field="*{freightsDto[__${itemStat.index}__].weight}">
                        <div class="input-group-prepend">
                            <span class="input-group-text">lbs</span>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-3 plts">
                    <label class="row custom-control-label">How many pallets</label>
                    <div class="row input-group mb-3">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control"
                               th:field="*{freightsDto[__${itemStat.index}__].pallets}">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

             
            <hr>
              </li>
                          
                                                    <li class="listName">
                    <div class="row mtp">
                        <div class="col-sm-8 w-50 desc">
                            <label class="row">Item description</label>
                            <input id="addInput" class="row form-control" type="text" th:field="*{freightsDto[__${itemStat.index}__].name}" required="required">
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-sm-2">
                            <div class="inblk mlt custom-control custom-radio custom-control-inline mtp" th:each="modelMap : ${T(com.payara.common.AssetCondition).values()}">
                                <input type="radio" th:field="*{freightsDto[__${itemStat.index}__].assetCondition}" class="custom-control-input" th:value="${modelMap}"> <!-- this works fine with modelMap.displayValue -->
                                <label class="custom-control-label" th:for="${#ids.next('freightsDto[__${itemStat.index}__].assetCondition')}"
                               th:text="${modelMap.displayValue}">Asset condition</label>
                        <!-- this works fine with itemStat.count too -->
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row mtp">
                <div class="col-sm-3 pack">
                    <label for="packaging" class="row custom-control-label">Packaging</label>
                    <select name="Packaging" id="packaging" class="row form-select">
                        <option th:each="modelMap : ${T(com.payara.common.PackageType).values()}"
                                th:value="${modelMap}" th:text="${modelMap.displayValue}" size="50">
                        </option>
                    </select>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-3 dim">
                    <label style="margin-left: 2px;" class="row custom-control-label">Dimensions</label>
                    <div class="input-group mb-3">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" th:field="*{freightsDto[__${itemStat.index}__].length}">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" th:field="*{freightsDto[__${itemStat.index}__].width}">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" th:field="*{freightsDto[__${itemStat.index}__].height}">
                        <div class="input-group-prepend">
                            <span class="input-group-text">L x W x H (inch)</span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-3 wght">
                    <label style="margin-left: 2px;" class="row custom-control-label">Weight</label>
                    <div class="input-group mb-3">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" th:field="*{freightsDto[__${itemStat.index}__].weight}">
                        <div class="input-group-prepend">
                            <span class="input-group-text">lbs</span>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-3 plts">
                    <label class="row custom-control-label">How many pallets</label>
                    <div class="row input-group mb-3">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control"
                               th:field="*{freightsDto[__${itemStat.index}__].pallets}">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

             
            <hr>
              </li>
                          
  
           </ul>

        </div>
        
        
        
        
       
  
          <div id="toggleBtn" class="row mtp">
                <button id="addBtn" class="col-sm-12">
                    Add more shipments
                </button>
            </div>
           
       </div>
```

Comment: Why would you want to do this using JavaScript, is there anything “dynamic” about this structure? If every LI contains a span with that class as the structure above currently is, then you can easily do this using CSS.

Comment: yes it is dynamic.. look at the html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the list of elements with class "listName", and change the first element of that list.

**Javascript**

```
window.onload = function(){
   // Get elements with class name 
   var elements_array = document.getElementsByClassName("listName");
   // Change first element
   elements_array[0].style.display = "block";
}
```

```js
window.onload = function(){
  // Get elements with class name 
  var elements_array = document.getElementsByClassName("listName");
  // Change first element
  elements_array[0].style.display = "block";
}
```

```css
.listName {
    display: none;
 }
```

```html
<html>
  <body>
    <div class="listHolder">
      <ul class="list">
            <li>
              <span class="listName">Macbook</span>
            </li>
            <li>
              <span class="listName">Amazon Firestick</span>
            </li>
            <li>
              <span class="listName">Keyboard</span>
            </li>
            <li>
              <span class="listName">Headphones</span>
            </li>
            <li>
              <span class="listName">Airpods</span>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: edited my answer @tylerdurden , maybe that's what you are looking for, don't know if you have any javascript written. (Dots can be hidden by moving the class from <span> to <li>)

Comment: i updated the code to show the real code i have maybe if you look at the real code it will change your code to the right one.. i tried what you showed me before i created the post and it didn't work .. maybe there is something wrong with the selectors or something

Comment: ok i had a mistake in my code i had .listHolder {
    display: none;
}  instead of .listName  .... your code worked fine thanks

Answer (score 1):

I think you can do with JavaScript

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    // create the function with JavaScript
    function removerClass() {
        // get all elements with listName class
        let element = document.getElementsByClassName("listName");
        // get the first element
        element = element[0];
        // remove the element's class
        element.classList.remove("listName");
    }

    // call the function when the page is loaded 
    removerClass() 
</script>
```

I hope it's usefull

Comment: i am not removing i want it to show not remove